# Holo theme dont work

Tags: android

I create empty app. ActionBar: set icon and title. Content: TextView with text "Hello!". In style.xml

```html
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

</style>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

</style>
```

SDK

```html
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

Android 4.4.4 in my phone.

First proble it is that when start app with theme Appcompat logo didnt show.

Secod problem it is that I cant set Holo theme.

manifest

```html
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

style.xml

```html
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it directly in manifest file without calling styles

```
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" >
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you are using AppCompat in another activity.  "java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity."